# Rails Glyphicons are not showing up (BS 2.3.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a very hard time displaying any Glyphicons in my Rails app. I can't display any of the BS 2.3 doc icon sets anywhere in my app. I actually downloaded a gem with some icons and those work great but I want to use the BS ones. What are some possible reaosns for this? This is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '= 3.0.1'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'font-icons-rails', :git=> 'git://github.com/shorelabs/font-icons-rails.git'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development do
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

For example, this line of code wont produce any icons in my Nav partial:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to(new_category_path) do %>
    <i class="icon-plus"></i>
    New Category
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Comment: Did you import `font-icons` in one of your stylesheets?

Comment: Wow! yes...I guess i wasn't supposed to and forget since it was required to with the font icon rails gem. So I am only able to use one or the other? What's the best way to use both or multiple different ones plus BS icons?